# Windows Batch Search and Replace Question

Tags: windows, search, batch-file, replace

I have a small batch file to search and replace within a batch file.  I am having difficulty removing things (eg replacing some text with a null value).  Am sure it is simple but not found anything by searching!

This is the file:

Where you see xxxxx and yyyyy is where I need a blank!

Cheers.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist %~n1.bugs%~x1 del %~n1.bugs%~x1

if not exist "%1" (echo this file does not exist...)&goto :eof

set FIND_LOGO_1_DATA=logo_data_0 101
set FIND_LOGO_2_DATA=logo_data_0 102
set FIND_LOGO_3_DATA=logo_data_0 103
set FIND_LOGO_4_DATA=logo_data_0 104
set FIND_LOGO_5_DATA=logo_data_0 107
set FIND_LOGO_6_DATA=logo_data_0 108
set FIND_LOGO_7_DATA=logo_data_0 109
set FIND_LOGO_8_DATA=logo_data_0 110
set FIND_LOGO_9_DATA=logo_data_0 105
set FIND_LOGO_10_DATA=logo_data_0 106


for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%1) do (

   set write=%%a
   if "%%a"=="logo_0 2" set write=xxxxx
   if "%%a"=="logo_0 1" set write=yyyyy
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_1_DATA%" set write=logo_0 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_2_DATA%" set write=logo_1 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_3_DATA%" set write=logo_2 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_4_DATA%" set write=logo_3 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_5_DATA%" set write=logo_4 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_6_DATA%" set write=logo_5 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_7_DATA%" set write=logo_6 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_8_DATA%" set write=logo_7 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_9_DATA%" set write=logo_8 1
   if "%%a"=="%FIND_LOGO_10_DATA%" set write=logo_9 1


   (echo !write!)>>%~n1.bugs%~x1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm seeing this correctly, then you just want to output a blank line in the two cases where you currently have `xxxxx` and `yyyyy`, right?

If that's the case, then it's actually very easy. You just have to set `write` to nothing:

```
set write=
```

and alter the line where you `echo` that variable in the following way:

```
echo.!write!
```

This will cause echo to output an empty line if `write` is empty and suppress the "ECHO is off." message (also documented [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/04/03/8352719.aspx)).